# Handling image upload with BlobstoreUploadHandler and returning a JSON message

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to upload an image to a URL created with create_upload_url(), handle it with the default BlobstoreUploadHandler and return an JSON message back to the client with the get_serving_url() URL of the image. My code is as follows:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        response = {}

        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

        response['error'] = False
        response['message'] = "Image uploaded."
        response['image_url'] = images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key())

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/_ih/upload_handler/', UploadHandler),
    ], debug=True)
```

The problem is that no response is received on the client side. The AppEngine logs show a status of 200 on the request. When the request is made with flash, the status code is 200 and no response body, however using HTML5 will output a status of "(cancelled)". I have no idea what is going on. From all the code snippets that I've seen on the internet this should work. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it was an HTML5 Cross-Origin Resource Sharing problem. You can fix this by adding the correct headers on the response:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        response = {}

        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

        response['error'] = False
        response['message'] = "Image uploaded."
        response['image_url'] = images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key())


        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST") 
        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle uploads and return JSON response, you need to redirect from the upload_handler to a handler that'll return the JSON response.

Here's an example:

```
class FileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):

    def post(self):
        blob_info = self.get_uploads()[0]       
        self.redirect(self.uri_for("successfulUpload",blob_key = blob_info.key()))


class SuccessfulUpload(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, blob_Key):
        response['error'] = False
        response['message'] = "Image uploaded."
        response['image_url'] = images.get_serving_url(blobstore.BlobKey(blob_Key))
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

Comment: Even though that would work, the BlobstoreUploadHandler doesn't have to return a redirect anymore. The strangest part is that it used to work on another project and I've seen many people do this as well. I'll try testing it with older SDKs.

Comment: @andrei Are you experiencing the issue on the dev or on live site?

Comment: You also can use multiple inheritance : class Uploader(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, BaseHandler): and you do not have to redirect.

Comment: @Bert I'm experiencing this issue on both dev and live site. I've tried extending both BlobstoreUploadHandler and the usual webapp.RequestHandler (webapp2.RequestHandler as well) it doesn't work. Having a simple handler with just one line of setting the body won't work either. I don't know how this can just stop working overnight. I'm either doing a very subtle mistake or the guys from the blobstore servers messed up something.